# how to insert data in db using liferay portlet

Tags: java, mysql, liferay

How to insert data in MySql using Liferay?

I have created Edit.jsp, view.jsp from edit.jsp I want to enter data and in view.jsp I want to show my data. This data which is enter in edit.jsp should be stored in my mysql table. I have created service.xml, portal-ext.properties.

I have java file also. Please tell me where should I write my insertion logic to store my data in to database.

Here is my Java code. I have edit.jsp file and view.jsp file, i have created table using service.xml file and I put my portal-ext.properties in classes folder. Is any thing missing? I am new in liferay

```
package com.portlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.GenericPortlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.PortletMode;
import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences;
import javax.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcher;
import javax.portlet.PortletURL;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portlet.model.testimonial;
import com.liferay.portlet.service.testimonialLocalServiceUtil;

public class Testimonial extends GenericPortlet {

    protected String editJSP;
    protected String viewJSP;
    private static Log _log = LogFactory.getLog(Testimonial.class);

    public void init() throws PortletException 
    {
        editJSP = getInitParameter("edit-jsp");
        viewJSP = getInitParameter("view-jsp");
    }

    public void doEdit(RenderRequest renderRequest,RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException 
    {
        renderResponse.setContentType("text/html");
        PortletURL addNameURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
        addNameURL.setParameter("addName", "addName");
        renderRequest.setAttribute("addNameURL", addNameURL.toString());
        include(editJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,RenderResponse renderResponse) throws  IOException, PortletException
    {
        PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
        String username = (String) prefs.getValue("name", "");
        String area=(String)prefs.getValue("area", "testimonial");
        String email=(String)prefs.getValue("email", "");
        String subject=(String)prefs.getValue("subject", "");
        String company=(String)prefs.getValue("company", "");
        String designation=(String)prefs.getValue("designation", "");

        if (username.equalsIgnoreCase ("")) 
        {
            username = "";
        }

        renderRequest.setAttribute("userName", username);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("area",area);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("email",email);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("subject",subject);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("designation",designation);
        renderRequest.setAttribute("company",company);

        include(viewJSP, renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse  actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException 
    {       
        String addName = actionRequest.getParameter("addName");

        if (addName != null)
        {
            PortletPreferences prefs = actionRequest.getPreferences();
            prefs.setValue("name", actionRequest.getParameter("username"));
            prefs.setValue("area",actionRequest.getParameter("area"));
            prefs.setValue("email",actionRequest.getParameter("email"));
            prefs.setValue("subject",actionRequest.getParameter("subject"));
            prefs.setValue("designation",actionRequest.getParameter("designation"));
            prefs.setValue("company",actionRequest.getParameter("company"));

            prefs.store();

            testimonial testimonial = null;

            try {
                testimonialLocalServiceUtil.createtestimonial(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            testimonial.setSubject(actionRequest.getParameter("subject"));
            testimonial.setArea(actionRequest.getParameter("area"));
            testimonial.setUsername(actionRequest.getParameter("username"));
            testimonial.setEmail(actionRequest.getParameter("email"));
            testimonial.setCompany(actionRequest.getParameter("company"));
            testimonial.setDesignation(actionRequest.getParameter("designation"));

            try {
                testimonialLocalServiceUtil.addtestimonial(testimonial);
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            actionResponse.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);    
        }   
    }

    protected void include(String path, RenderRequest renderRequest,RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException 
    {
        PortletRequestDispatcher portletRequestDispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path);

        if (portletRequestDispatcher == null) 
        {
            _log.error(path + " is not a valid include");
        }
        else
        {
            portletRequestDispatcher.include(renderRequest, renderResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as above mention in my earlier post. i create table using service.xml, then build service but i cant see table in database.
i put portal-ext.properties in classes

Comment: hello tell me .. which step i should follow?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was mislead by your mysql tag. You want to presist PortletPreferences I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use either Liferay default API for accessing and inserting data in default Liferay tables or if you want to access/insert in Custom(self-made) tables in Database, then you have to use Liferay Service Builder.

In your question - you can create your tables manually in database first.

Then you can make `service.xml` and build the service using the ant build file which will give you the `LocalServiceUtil` classes. In your case it is `testimonialLocalServiceUtil` class.

Also as per your code, the `processAction` method overriding is correct.

Please check the table and columns specifications in service.xml. It should not have any problem.

Here is a link which may help you -

http://www.phloxblog.in/liferay-service-builder-step-step/

And, if you get any exception, please share those to us, so that we can understand the problem area.

Thanks

Comment: how to use liferay default API?

Comment: when i right click on myportlet i cant see service-builder option. i have to make service.xml file manually. is something missing in it?

Comment: Those are liferay default classes and methods which are exposed as library in SDK. But you can not use default classes and methods for custom tables. There you have to make service through service builder.

Comment: Be sure, you are in "Liferay" Perspective in Eclipse. Then select the project ->new->Liferay Service Builder. Thanks.

Comment: Using your post i understand that i have to create table in mysql query browser manually.. and then create table in service.xml and then rebuild the service? am i correct sir?

Comment: But sir i cant see ->new->Liferay Service Builder in my eclipse.. so i have to create service.xml as a file..

Comment: Yes..this is the way, we create our services for the custom tables. There may be other way around, but we do our work in this way. Thanks.

Comment: The service.xml file will aumatically be created once you go through the service builder wizard...

Comment: but sir i cant see the service builder tab in my eclipse.. so is there any plug-ins missing?

Comment: "Service Builder" is not a tab, it is within the menu - "New"-->>"Liferay Service Builder". If it is missing, then you should re-install liferay-eclipse.By-the-way please do not call "Sir", it is developer to developer forum. Thanks.

Comment: i am using ubuntu os..so how to get liferay-eclipse? i want to re-install. n i want setup, kindly help me..

Comment: You can have all required downloads in http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide link

Comment: thanks dada .. i got the set up. but i need your help more.is my insertion code is correct?

Comment: If your table wise service is correct, then We have seen no problem in your insertion logic. Only to note you can use direct - Long uomId = Long.valueOf(actionRequest.getParameter("uom")); Otherwise we see no problem here.

Comment: where should i write this? sorry i am newbie to liferay..
Long uomId = Long.valueOf(actionRequest.getParameter("uom"));
is it required without it can not run?

Comment: <service-builder package-path="com.liferay.portlet" auto-namespace-tables="true">
    <author>kapil</author>
    <namespace>library</namespace>
     <entity name="testimonial" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
    
    <!-- PK fields -->
    
<column name="testimonialId" type="long" primary ="true"/>
   <column name="subject" type="String"/>
    <column name="area" type="String" />
    <column name="username" type="String" />
    <column name="email" type="String" />
 <column name="company" type="String" />
 <column name="designation" type="String"/>
 </entity>
</service-builder>

Comment: this is my table please check.. i have create using service.xml is this correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please view it. Also your service.xml is correct. Please work with it. If any problem is there, we will review those.

Comment: i have download eclipse from that link which u provide.. i have ubuntu 32 bit. i delete my old eclipse from my local drive then i unzip my new latest download eclipse version. but when i try to see service builder still i cant see .. please help me what i should do ... :(

Comment: hello @piyas De are u there?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the below steps:

```
    File-->new-->Liferay Project
    Right Click on WEB-INF-->new-->Liferay Service Builder-->Enter the package path(com.database) and namespace(A)-->Finish
    Now you have service.xml-->change the properties accoding to your requirement-->save it
    Right click on service.xml-->Liferay-->Build Services.
    Now you will get  some folders,classes and interfaces under docroot/ WEB-INF/src
    change in the  LiferayLocalServiceImpl.java  under com.database.service.impl
    create one package  like com.portlet in docroot/ WEB-INF/src -->create a class and continue the application
```

service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.database">
    <author>name</author>
    <namespace>S</namespace>

    <entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="fooId" type="long" primary="true" />

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="userId" type="long" />
        <column name="bookName" type="String" />
        <column name="author" type="String" />

    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

In jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
    <portlet:actionURL var="addBURL" name="addB"/>

    <aui:form method="post" action="<%=addBURL.toString()%>" name="fm"
        id="fm">
    <!--    <input type="text" name="bookName"/>

        <input type="text" name="author"/> -->

            <aui:input name="bookName" label="BookName" type="text"></aui:input>
            <aui:input name="author" label="Author" type="text"></aui:input>
            <aui:button type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <!-- <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit"> -->
    </aui:form>
```

com.database.service.impl.BookLocalServiceImpl

```
    package com.database.service.impl;

    import com.database.model.Book;
    import com.database.service.base.BookLocalServiceBaseImpl;
    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;

    public class BookLocalServiceImpl extends BookLocalServiceBaseImpl {

        public Book aaddBook(Book bookParam) {

            Book book;

            try {
                book = bookPersistence.create(counterLocalService
                        .increment(Book.class.toString()));
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return book = null;
            }
            book.setAuthor(bookParam.getAuthor());
            book.setBookName(bookParam.getBookName());
            book.setCompanyId(bookParam.getCompanyId());
            book.setUserId(bookParam.getUserId());
            try {
                return bookPersistence.update(book, false);
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return book;
        }

    }
```

com.portlet
        Demo Class

```
    package com.portlet;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
    import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
    import javax.portlet.PortletException;

    import com.database.model.Book;
    import com.database.model.impl.BookImpl;
    import com.database.service.BookLocalServiceUtil;
    import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

    public class Demo extends MVCPortlet{

        public void addB(ActionRequest actionRequest,
                ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
            System.out.println("Action");
            String author=actionRequest.getParameter("author");
            String bookName=actionRequest.getParameter("bookName");
            Book book=new BookImpl();
            book.setAuthor(author);
            book.setBookName(bookName);
            BookLocalServiceUtil.aaddBook(book);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with @kartik about calling `Book book = new BookImpl()`;
Use `Book book = BookLocalServiceUtil.createBook(0)`instead

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/79177774

And for saving I would also recommend this article.

https://javaeasyforu.blogspot.de/2014/06/insert-data-into-db-using-service.html